# Conditional SASS Variables using mixin's

Tags: css, sass

I am currently using this mixin:

```
@mixin isMobile() {
  html[data-browser*="Mobile"] & {
    @content;
  }
}
```

And I want to use this mixin to conditionally apply to a variable, like below:

```
$div-height: 20px;
@include isMobile() {
  $div-height: 10px;
}
```

I know this is not the proper way of doing it, and I've also tried the following below with no success. How can I properly try this conditional? Thanks!

```
@if (html[data-browser*="Mobile"]) {
  $div-height: 20px;
} @else {
  $div-height: 10px;
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line? `html[data-browser*="Mobile"] & {`

Answer (score 1):

The conditional part has to be in the mixin itself.

```
@mixin isMobile($type) {
  $div-height: 0;
  html[data-browser*="Mobile"] {
    @if($type == 'A'){
      $div-height: 20px;
    }
    @else{
      $div-height: 10px;
    }
    height: $div-height;
    @content;
  }
}


@include isMobile('B'){
  color:black;
}


/*Output*/
html[data-browser*="Mobile"] {
  height: 10px;
  color: black;
}
```